# bullet point indenting not working - word 2007

Tags: ms-word, word-2007

Adjust List Indents function in Microsoft Word 2007 not working once the list goes past 10.

For heading 09 I open the Adjust List Indents function (By right clicking) and set the "Text Indent at" value to .05. This works. However for every heading after 10 following the exact same steps does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an indent issue, its the alignment in your numbering style.  Take some time to study this:
http://wordfaqs.mvps.org/NumberAlignment2007.htm#NumberedLists

A related MS Word skill which will leverage your efforts by an order of magnitude is to learn how to define custom **List Styles** and assign them to custom **Paragraph Styles**.  There is a very good tutorial here:
http://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html
and the analagous bullet list version:
http://shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html

I would add one level of efficiency to those tutorials:
You don't need to create a **Paragraph Style** for each list/bullet level.  You only need to assign a **Paragraph Style** to the first level.  When the **Paragraph Style** is applied to text, the **List Style** will be applied correctly to all levels based on the indentation of the list items.